# Can greenDAO only be used with Android?

Tags: java, greendao

I need DAO access to an Sqlite database, and greenDAO looks like it does just what I need.
All the documentation relates to using it on the Android platform, but I need it both on and off the Android platform - will it work this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

greenDAO relies on Android APIs for SQLite access and other things. Thus it cannot be used outside Android.